# Animation definintion with condition

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, mxml

how can i make animation MOVE definition with condition??

i have component and when i click on button then i want move this component 60 pixels right, next click again 60 pixels right and again..scene is 620 pixels width...when component is eg at position 600 and i click button, component move 20 pixels to right and 40 pixel left..then click button move component 60 pixels left..until it will at start scene..the same in left..component is eg at position 12..then click button - move it 12 left and 48 right...

is this animation with any condition defining in one animation sequence?? or i have to make still each click animation definition extra??

thanks pav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it through MoveEvent.MOVE event handler and 2 animation defin